# How to send mail in Asp.Net Mvc using dnxcore50?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is this even possible without using the old framework? I know there's something called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) and [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit). I've read somewhere that the author says it supports dot net core, but when I try to install it using nugetpacket manager they install into the dnx451 dependencies.

So I get the message that they are not available in DNX Core 5.0.

How can I install this nuget for dnxcore50? It seems strange to me that a basic thing like sending emails is not possible with this.

Comment: Can you consider using a service like Mandrill or Send Grid?

Comment: Yes, I will have to look into it. Thanks.